# PHP and MySQL query outputting data twice

Tags: php, mysql

I have a CMS Page module and when you go to a page it shows it twice. This is what calls the function:

```
$pages = new pages;
if(isset($_GET['action']) && ($_GET['action'] == "pages")){
if($_GET['action'] === 'pages' && isset($_GET['page'])){
$pages->pages();
} elseif ($_GET['action'] === 'pages' && !isset($_GET['page'])) {
$pages->pagelist();
}
$pages->pagesAdminBar();

if(isset($_GET['mode'])){
if($_GET['mode'] == "edit"){
$pages->editPage();
}
if($_GET['mode'] == "addpage"){
$pages->addpage();
}
if($_GET['mode'] == "pageadmin"){
$pages->pageadmin();
}
$pages->pagesAdminBar();
}
}
```

and this is the function:

```
public function pages(){
    global $dbc, $parser, $layout, $main, $settings, $core;

        if(isset($_GET['page'])){
        $page = mysqli_real_escape_string($dbc, $_GET['page']);

        if(!isset($_GET['page']) && !isset($_GET['action'])){
        $page = $settings['home_display'];
        }
        $query = "SELECT * FROM pages WHERE pagename = '$page'";
        $data = mysqli_query($dbc, $query);

        while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($data)) {

            echo '<div class="shadowbar">';
                echo'<h3>' . $row['pagename'] . '</h3>';
            $parsed = $parser->parse($row['body']);
                echo '<pre>'.$parsed.'</pre>';
            echo '</div>'; 
    }
    }
    }
```

but when I go to the page in the browser it shows the query data twice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your code in pages() is called twice because your class doesn't have a constructor and you have two lines
`$pages = new pages;` and `$pages->pages();` producing same results.

Answer (score 1):

Try DISTINCT select data. It will merge same rows as one.

```
SELECT DISTINCT * FROM pages WHERE pagename = '$page'
```

Try this might be work because sometime when calling $rows = mysqli_fetch_array($data) in while loop must be problem.

```
public function pages(){
    global $dbc, $parser, $layout, $main, $settings, $core;

        if(isset($_GET['page'])){
        $page = mysqli_real_escape_string($dbc, $_GET['page']);

        if(!isset($_GET['page']) && !isset($_GET['action'])){
        $page = $settings['home_display'];
        }
        $query = "SELECT * FROM pages WHERE pagename = '$page'";
        $data = mysqli_query($dbc, $query);

        $row = mysqli_fetch_array($data);
        echo '<div class="shadowbar">';
        echo'<h3>' . $row['pagename'] . '</h3>';
        $parsed = $parser->parse($row['body']);
        echo '<pre>'.$parsed.'</pre>';
        echo '</div>'; 
    }
    }
```

Comment: Hmm, so it's still doing it, which tells me that there must be something telling it to display twice

Comment: It's still outputting twice. If you look at http://ded.ccp2.us/cb/index.php?action=pages&page=Documentation%20-%20Intro You'll see what I mean. It is outputting twice but I can't see why

Comment: @Cheesecake How many columns are there in your data?  Besides pagename and body?  Perhaps, your data has versions of same documents?  Try `select distinct pagename, body from pages where ... ` instead of selecting all fields.  You can study results of the query in phpMyAdmin first to get some idea.

Comment: @TimothyHa The thing is, it shows what it should in PHPMyAdmin, but on the page it displays two. I'll edit my question to show all of the display settings

Comment: After changing it it shows a bunch of numbers and letters randomly. If you go the the same link above you'll see

Comment: @Cheesecake sorry i don't have no idea whats going on but never giveup try my other code which is remove foreach and get only the row.

Comment: @IsuruMadusanka Still happening, I'm gonna take a brake for a while and se if I can figure it out

Comment: @Cheesecake - did you check my answer below?